# jQuery Mobile Trouble with getting data from multiple dropdown lists

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm new to jQuery and javascript. I've been trying to make a simple application and having a lot of trouble getting the data that the user inputs. I have two drop down lists, and I just want to get the input from each one. It seems that I can only get one or the other. I'm obviously missing something.

```
<code> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Headers and Footers</title>
<!-- the three things that jQuery Mobile needs to work -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../jquery.mobile-1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css" />
<script src="../jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../jquery.mobile-1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>

</head>
<body>

  <!-- This is the first page -->
<section id="firstpage" data-role="page" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
         <h1 style="text-align:left; margin-left:20px;">Converter</h1>
        <a href="#" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right">Options</a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-content">
        <label for="dose-input" id="dose-input2">Enter Dose of starting Drug</label>
        <input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" placeholder="Enter Starting Drug">

        <form>
<div class="ui-field-contain">
<label for="select-native-1">Choose starting Drug:</label>
<select name="select-native-1" id="select-native-1" data-native-menu="false">
    <option>Choose Starting...</option>
    <option value="1">Drug 1</option>
    <option value="2">Drug 2</option>
    <option value="3">Drug 3</option>
    <option value="4">Drug 4</option>
    <option value="5">Drug 5</option>
    <option value="6">Drug 6</option>
</select>

</div>
</form>

<div class="ui-field-contain">
<label for="select-end">Choose ending Drug:</label>
<select name="select-end" id="select-end" data-native-menu="false">
    <option>Choose ending...</option>
    <option value="1">Drug 1 </option>
    <option value="2">Drug 2</option>
    <option value="3">Drug 3</option>
    <option value="4">Drug 4</option>
    <option value="5">Drug 5</option>
    <option value="6">Drug 6</option>
</select>
</div>


<fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
<div class="Clear"><button type="button" id="clear" data-theme="c">Clear</button></div>
<div class="Submit"><button type="button" id="submit" data-theme="b">Submit</button></div>   
</fieldset>

<script>
  $('#submit').click(function() {


 $( "input" )
.keyup(function() {
 var value = $( this ).val();
 $( "p" ).text( value );
  alert(value);
})
  .keyup();
  var selected_end = $('#select-end').val();
  alert(selected_end);
  var starting_drug = $('#select-native-1"').val();
  alert(starting_drug);

}); 

</script>


 </div>


</section>
</body>
</html>  </code>
```

If I have it set this way, I will only get the value of the entered dosage and the option of the end of the drug. I won't be able to get the option for the beginning of the drug. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is pretty confusing... To get values from select menus on submit just do:

```
$(document).on("click", "#submit", function(event)
{
    var dose = $("#dose-input").val();
    var drug_start = $("#select-start").val();
    var drug_end = $("#select-end").val();
    alert(dose + "\n" + drug_start + "\n" + drug_end);
});
```

Be sure to check for default values on submit.
Check out complete **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7v8xE/)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This script gives me "undefined, undefined, 4". 4 being the 4th option in the end drug drop down that I selected. Very bizzare.

Comment: Have you changed the element id's to match the script?

Comment: You're right on the the element id's was wrong, so this fixed drug_start and drug_end, but dose is showing up blank.

Comment: nevermind. I moved the id down one line, and now it's working great. Thanks for your help.